# Leapfrog Game in C

Tags: c

I am making a frog game. There is a Lilly pad in the middle with three frogs on each side. The goal of the game is to make the frogs move as far as it possibly can. A frog can only jump in the direction it is facing and it can only hop over one frog at a time to a Lilly pad.

This is what it is supposed to look like starting the game

(1:>  (2:> (3:> ____ <:4) <:5)<:6)

Sample move:

move frog 4

(1:>  (2:> (3:>  <:4) ____ <:5) <:6)

**My problem is I can't figure out how to implement a makeMove() method that modifies the frog array list based on the number of the frog the user wants to move.**

Here is a piece of what I have:

```
int frogToJump; //The frog the user wishes to jump
const char* string[7] ; //An array for storing the frogs

//The array of frogs
void frogString(){
string[0]= "\n(1:>";
string[1]= "(2:>";
string[2]= "(3:>";
string[3]= " ___ ";
string[4]= "<4:)";
string[5]= "<5:)";
string[6]= "<6:)";


//Prints the array of frogs
for(int i= 0; i< 7; i++){
    printf("%s",string[i]);
 }


//Gets user input for the frog they want to move

printf("\n""\n" "Move Frog: ");
scanf("%d", &frogToJump);
```

}

Comment: Right now you *can't* move the "frogs" around, because you keep formatting in the strings.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you could do it with *two* arrays: One containing the string pointers and that you swap around, and one array that contains the *position* of the frogs.

So to move one frog one step left (unless it's the left-most frog) you first swap the pointers in the string pointer array, then update the positions in the position array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char history[24][8];//24 : 3*4*2
const char *init_state = ">>> <<<";
const char *end_state  = "<<< >>>";

void print_history(int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i <= n; ++i)
        puts(history[i]);
}

void next_state(int i){
    int loc;
    if(strcmp(history[i], end_state)==0){
        print_history(i);
        exit(0);
    }
    for(loc=0; loc < 8; ++loc){
        if(history[i][loc] == '>'){
            if(loc + 2 < 8 && history[i][loc+2] == ' '){
                strcpy(history[i+1], history[i]);
                history[i+1][loc+2] = '>';
                history[i+1][loc] = ' ';
                next_state(i+1);
            }
            if(loc + 1 < 8 && history[i][loc+1] == ' '){
                strcpy(history[i+1], history[i]);
                history[i+1][loc+1] = '>';
                history[i+1][loc] = ' ';
                next_state(i+1);
            }
        } else if(history[i][loc] == '<'){
            if(loc - 2 >= 0 && history[i][loc-2] == ' '){
                strcpy(history[i+1], history[i]);
                history[i+1][loc-2] = '<';
                history[i+1][loc] = ' ';
                next_state(i+1);
            }
            if(loc - 1 >= 0 && history[i][loc-1] == ' '){
                strcpy(history[i+1], history[i]);
                history[i+1][loc-1] = '<';
                history[i+1][loc] = ' ';
                next_state(i+1);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    strcpy(history[0], init_state);
    next_state(0);
    return 0;
}
```